# TypeScript add overload to method in another definitions file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Given a class defined in a 3rd-party `d.ts` definitions file which I cannot edit:

```
export declare class MyClass {
  someMethod(a: any, b: any);
  moreMethods();
  // lots more methods here
}
```

The `someMethod` method requires a certain type for param `b` based on the type of param `a`.  However the definitions file does not represent that constraint as both as `any`.

Is it possible to add overload definitions for `someMethod` in my own `d.ts` - without having to redefine ALL the methods/props on the original definition?  I know it can be done easily if the class was an interface instead.

Something like this:

```
export declare class MyClass {
  // add override declaration to ensure `b` is a string if `a` is a number.
  someMethod(a: number, b: string); 
}
```

The above seems to *replace* the original class definition, which means it now *only* has my override method in it, not `moreMethods()` etc.

In reality, this question relates the the Angular `MatDialog` component that defines `open` as:

```
open<T, D = any, R = any>(
   componentOrTemplateRef: ComponentType<T> | TemplateRef<T>, 
   config?: MatDialogConfig<D>): MatDialogRef<T, R>;
```

which means I can instantiate a dialog, but pass in the wrong dialog data object (type `D`).  I would like to add definitions like:

```
// ensure that FooDialogComponent is passed FooDialogData for config
open<T, D = any, R = any>(
   componentOrTemplateRef: typeof FooDialogComponent, 
   config?: MatDialogConfig<FooDialogData>): MatDialogRef<T, R>;
// ensure that BarDialogComponent is passed BarDialogData for config
open<T, D = any, R = any>(
   componentOrTemplateRef: typeof BarDialogComponent, 
   config?: MatDialogConfig<BarDialogData>): MatDialogRef<T, R>;
```

**UPDATE**
So following @hackape's answer, I created this code (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAWwgEwK4BthwLIE9soZYDeAUHHKJLHAMboCGAzk3ACrBPxkUULAwAFigAUDAFxwGAO1wBKOMTgBfcrxkQhwKNgHDkYyTPmKVas6tJVo8ZMHoMoWRIUw58rkmus0AltJhtADMGWiwOLkVzOAB6GLgIADdtdAgGZDgAd18hOCYwe18g31o4GFwC6P4hUQk4aVQEACNtOUlEiF9kAG41VUtSRMcpAEY4AF564Ez3AjRMADoImBE5Xri4f0D0dF8mYGl9hKCg7VYmzUE4QW0scTlSBhGF6v0RACYRgGY1x+eNLQ6PSiEZrIA) which works as expected.

*However*, as previously mentioned I was using this to add overloads to the Angular Mat Dialog component, and it doesn't seem to work with that.

```
declare module '@angular/material/dialog' {
    export interface MatDialog  {
        someTestMethod(): void;
    }
}
```

Anywhere using the dialog component now will only see `someTestMethod()` not all the existing method on the MatDialog class defined in the angular component.  Is there some difference because it is adding to an external npm module?

Comment: A class declaration also creates an interface declaration so might changing `export declare class MyClass {` to `export declare interface MyClass {` work? Interfaces appear to merge unlike classes.

Answer (score 0):

In TS declaring `class` also create an interface of the same name, so in theory you can augment the `MyClass.open` signature from outside using interface merging technique.

```
declare module 'existing-module' {
  interface MyClass {
    someMethod(a: number, b: string): void;
  }
}
```

However, this is not going to solve your problem. Interface merging can only add-to existing signature, you can overload the `.open()` method, but never override it.

That existing `.open()` signature is already too loose. Although you can overload it with a stricter signature, but anything that violates the constraint will fallback to the the existing loose signature, thus invalidate the constraint and raise no error.

Comment: Thanks.  Agree that it won't raise an error, but just wanted the intellisense to help with passing in the current dialog data for a specific component.  Also I did mean overload instead of override, sorry.  Will update the question with a little more info.